# How can I simply return boolean with angular 6 .subscribe()

Tags: angular

New to Angular and I can't find anything to help me with this, would appreciate your help.

Prefer to handle this situation without rxjs; ie. .pipe(map(...))

The api responds with either:

status(200) { token: "..." } --or-- status(400)

```
login(credentials) {
  return this.http.post('.../api/authenticate', credentials)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
        return true;
      },
      () => {
        return false;
      });
}
```

How does one simply return boolean?

Comment: You want to return a boolean to what? It's an async method. What's the intended logic here?

Comment: it's called with name + password creds, if true go to home, else stay at login and show alert.

Comment: So add that logic to your subscription handler. `subscribe((response) => {/* go to home */}, () => {/* show alert */});`

Comment: one moment while I try this...

Comment: This works, thanks; I was routing from the route component, now routing from service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, This is not the correct implementation. When you hit the subsscribe method, it will automatically hits the API in background without stucking script (over different thread). You can use a callback method to achieve your desire results, checkout the logic mentioned below,

Your login function should looks something like this,

```
login(credentials, callback) {
  return this.http.post('.../api/authenticate', credentials)
    .subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        callback(response.status);
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
      });
}
```

Call this function this this,

```
login(credentials, (status) => {
    console.log(status);
});
```

Comment: you'll get the response status in `status` param..,

Comment: This is what I was looking for; I can keep the route handling in the correct component this way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want status as well in response the add one json object in your post call.for ex:

```
 return this.http.post(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add logic to your `subscribe` call to navigate according to the response as you stated.

like this -

```
login(credentials) {
  return this.http.post('.../api/authenticate', credentials)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
      },
      () => {
        alert('Error message here');
      });
}
```

No need to return anything from the `subscribe` call, or you can simply call any method too depending upon the response.